# Populate Listbox from 2 combobox selections

Tags: excel, vba

Here's what I have so far. I'm attempting to populate my listbox based on the 2 combobox selections the user makes in a userform.

```
Private Sub Product_Type_Box_Change()
Dim Products_List As String
Dim M As Integer
Dim Manufacturers As String
Dim Product_Type As String
Dim DCSProgram2 As Workbook
Dim MLast As Long
Dim PLast As Long
Dim p As Integer

Set DCSProgram2 = ActiveWorkbook
Manufacturers = Me.MFG_Box.Value
Product_Type = Me.Product_Type_Box.Value

With DCSProgram2.Sheets("MFG_DATA")
    MLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For M = 1 To MLast
           PLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
               For p = 1 To PLast
                   If .Cells(M, 1).Value = Manufacturers And .Cells(p, 1).Value = Product_Type Then
                      With Products_Box
                          .AddItem "yay it works"


                      End With
                   End If
                Next p
            Next M

 End With
 End Sub
```

I've tried populating the list box without the `And` statement and had success with my variable `Manufacturers`. Below is an example of what my data is like.

```
Item    Manufacturers   Product Type   Other Data
 1        MFG 1           Tools           4558
 2        MFG 2           Parts           4455
 3        MFG 1           Tools           4585
 4        MFG 3           Screws          6845
```

So `if Manufacturers = MFG 1 and Productype = Tools then Products_Box` would have the value `yay it works`. If I can figure this part out in the end I would like to list data from my spread sheet in the listbox so a user could pick one of multiple entries. Let me know if I can make anything more clear.

Thank You,

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

If `Products_Box` is some other list box on the same UserForm then you're missing a `Me.` before it.

Furthermore if I got your aim right, I'd point out what follows:

- you're looping unnecessarily
- range type `AutoFilter` method would come in very handy
- the same `Products_Box` treatment would be needed for `MFG_Box` `_Change` event

for all what above I'd refactor your code as follows

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub MFG_Box_Change()

Call UpdateProduct_Box

End Sub

Private Sub Product_Type_Box_Change()

Call UpdateProduct_Box

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProduct_Box()
Dim Manufacturers As String
Dim Product_Type As String

Dim dataDB As Range

With Me
    If .MFG_Box.ListIndex < 0 Or .Product_Type_Box.ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

    Manufacturers = .MFG_Box.Value
    Product_Type = .Product_Type_Box.Value
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MFG_DATA") '<== be sure which workbook you want to refer to: ActiveWorkbook (the one whose window is currently active in excel session) or ThisWorkbook (the one in which this macro resides)
    Set dataDB = .Range("A1:D1").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

With dataDB
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Manufacturers ' filter data on Manufacturer
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Product_Type ' filter data again on Product Type
    Call UpdateListBox(Me.Products_Box, dataDB, 4)
    .AutoFilter 'remove filters
End With

End Sub


Sub UpdateListBox(LBToFill As MSForms.ListBox, dataDB As Range, columnToList As Long)
Dim cell As Range, dataValues As Range

With LBToFill
    If dataDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > dataDB.Columns.Count Then 'if all data rows have been hidden then there last headers only, which count up to data columns number
        Set dataValues = dataDB.Offset(1).Resize(dataDB.Rows.Count - 1)
       .Clear ' clear listbox before adding new elements
        For Each cell In dataValues.Columns(columnToList).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .AddItem cell.Value
        Next cell
    Else
        .Clear ' no match -> clear listbox
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have code in Private Sub MFG_Box_Change(), do i put the Call at the beginning or end? I tried both ways and it does not populate the listbox with the cell value.

Comment: as you see in my code, "Call UpdateProduct_Box" is the one and only statement in both "Private Sub MFG_Box_Change()" and "Private Sub UpdateProduct_Box()".  While "Private Sub UpdateProduct_Box() " must be in the same UserForm module and  "Sub UpdateListBox(...) can be in any module of your project